# Is it possible to have single sign on for 3rd party azure remote apps?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, remoteapp

I am a developer working on a think client application. One of our customers wants us to provide hosting for the application and I have set up azure remote app for this. The customer is asking if it will work with single sign on.

From what I can see it can work if I have access to their directory. For example if I could join their domain or change my default directory to be their directory it should work. Is this good practice though? From what I see the only way to do this is give their administrators access to my subscription.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Remote App offers two deployment options
- RemoteApp cloud deployment enables user logon with Microsoft account or corporate credentials federated with Azure Active Directory
- RemoteApp hybrid deployment enables full access to on-premises network, and user logon with corporate credentials federated with Azure Active Directory

So in both cases, you may have single sign on for your customer application, provided his current identity provider (for example On premise Active Directory) is federated with Azure Active Directory

Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: I believe they have on premise AD federated with Azure AD but if I try to add the users in my default directory it says "No user exists with this user name in a directory to which you have access". I guess maybe I need to know can they give me access, would they, and how do they do this.